# How to create custom keyboard like real keyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have to create custom keyboard like the real keyboard in iOS.
I need to do following like keyboard.

[image: I want to create my board like this]

like that.
How can i create like that?
Please tell me , because i'm just new beginner.

Comment: What language is this? Is there not an option for this language in the OS itself?

Comment: Ah ok, too bad. Hopefully they'll add official support one day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that I created that might help. Just fork it on GitHub and change the Punjabi characters to Myanmar. Most of the hard work is done for you :)

https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards

Answer (score 1):

With a custom view and custom buttons. The keyboard itself is something very easy to do, you just need to place some buttons on a view and then show that view.
Your real problem will be connecting the button actions to the text field.

You would have to check for the first responder and then add to its text the value corresponding to your custom keyboard. It will be an even more difficult problem to actually "type" those weird characters from the keyboard in the text field. I am not familiar with them, are those real ASCII characters?

Anyway, you're in for quite some work. It's not something very difficult to code, requiring some complicate algorithms, but the implementation will be tricky and complex, so be careful