# adding symbols in iphone keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, keyboard, uikeyboard

I've no idea to add special symbols to iphone keyboard like ® © ℠ ™ and many more.Does any one have any idea to add these symbols to the keyboard or any other alternative or adding these symbols in the textView ?

Comment: [UIKeyboardType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006896-CH3-SW22) please take a look at that .. these are the available keyboard type in iOS, So if it dint support your spec then you might need to write your own Custom Keyboard

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10614966/1059705 http://stackoverflow.com/a/9171950/1059705 http://stackoverflow.com/a/4644552/1059705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add symbols to a keyboard. You can create a custom keyboard view and set it for the text field using the `inputView` property. Or you can add a toolbar to the keyboard using the text field's `inputAccessoryView` property.

Several of these symbols can already be typed directly if the user adds the Emoji keyboard in the Settings app.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use emoji. Or make a custom keyboard.

[Create custom keyboard and configure it on your iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189287/create-custom-keyboard-and-configure-it-on-your-iphone)

Hope this helps!